# Changing decimal prices Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, decimal

Im making a sweetshop project for my apprenticeship and ive done some test runs and have got all my code working but then i get my brief and the prices are changed depending on the weight and have got decimal prices instead of whole E.G £0.0.1 i thought this wouldnt make a difference but im not sure whats stopping the plus and minus button from changing the decimal price.

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $key => $value) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 inner-container">
        <div class="card border">

      <div class="column-image" style=" background-image: url(<?php echo ($value['image']); ?>" >
   </div>
            <h2><?= $value['sweet_name'] ;?></h2><br/>

            <p>Price: £<?= $value['price'] ; ?></p>

        <p>Weight: <?= $value['weight'] ; ?>g</p>


    £<span id="prices"><?php echo ( $value['price'] );  ?></span><br/>

    <span id="weight"><?php echo ( $value['weight'] );  ?></span> g<br/>

    <button onclick="minus()"> - </button><span id="quantity"> 1 </span><button onclick="plus()"> + </button><br/>  

    <!-- runs the function addcookie in javascript and passes paramater id  -->
   <a href="/basket.php"><button class="column-button" onclick="addcookie(<?php echo  $value['id']; ?>)">Add to basket</button></a>

    </div>
<?php } ?>



<script>
    // these varibles are to not get [object HTMLSpanElement] 
    var weight = <?php echo ( $value['weight'] );  ?>;
    var price = <?php echo $value['price']; ?>; 
function addcookie(id){

    // element can be anything in HTML
    // innerHTML gets anything inside the html tags E.G quantity = 1

var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML; 



var id = <?php echo $value['id']; ?>;

// creates the cookie with a key and a value and also creates a path to be stored 
// this means i can access it on any page E.G basket.php

    document.cookie = "zzz_"+id+"_id="+id+"; ;path=/";
    document.cookie = "zzz_"+id+"_quantity="+quantity+"; ;path=/";
    document.cookie = "zzz_"+id+"_weight="+weight+"; ;path=/";
}
function plus(){

    // parseint changes strings into intergers 

    document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML = parseInt( document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML) +1;

    document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML = parseInt( document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML) +price;


    document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML = parseInt( document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML) +weight;

}
function minus(){

    if (document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML > 1){
    document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML = parseInt( document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML) -1;


    document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML = parseInt( document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML) -price;

    

    document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML = parseInt( document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML) -weight;

}
}

</script>
```

i'm just wondering what i'm doing wrong? i've tried changing my parseInt to a ParseDouble but there was no change at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. `parseFloat` is what you need. There's no such function as `ParseDouble` or `parseDouble`, so that was probably producing errors in your browser's Console (you didn't say whether you'd checked for those or not).

I've also added some calls to `.toFixed` so you don't end up with large trailing decimal places, but you can adjust that according to the level of accuracy / rounding you need.

Live demo:

```js
var weight = 5.2;
var price = 3.5;

function addcookie(id)
{
  // element can be anything in HTML
  // innerHTML gets anything inside the html tags E.G quantity = 1
  var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML;
  var id = 22;

  // creates the cookie with a key and a value and also creates a path to be stored 
  // this means i can access it on any page E.G basket.php
  //document.cookie = "zzz_" + id + "_id=" + id + "; ;path=/";
  //document.cookie = "zzz_" + id + "_quantity=" + quantity + "; ;path=/";
  //document.cookie = "zzz_" + id + "_weight=" + weight + "; ;path=/";
}

function plus()
{
  document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML) + 1;
  document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML) + price).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML = (parseFloat(document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML) + weight).toFixed(2);
}

function minus() 
{

  if (parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML) > 1) {
    document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML) - 1;
    document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML = ( parseFloat(document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML) - price).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML = ( parseFloat(document.getElementById('weight').innerHTML) - weight).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 inner-container">
  <div class="card border">
    <div class="column-image" style=" background-image: url(<?php echo ($value['image']); ?>">
    </div>
    <h2>
      Something
    </h2><br/>

    <p>Price: £ 3.5
    </p>

    <p>Weight: 5.2g
    </p>


    £<span id="prices">3.5</span><br/>

    <span id="weight">5.2</span> g<br/>

    <button onclick="minus()"> - </button><span id="quantity"> 1 </span><button onclick="plus()"> + </button><br/>

    <!-- runs the function addcookie in javascript and passes paramater id  -->
    <a href="/basket.php"><button class="column-button" onclick="addcookie(<?php echo  $value['id']; ?>)">Add to basket</button></a>

  </div>
```

Comment: Oh dear lord you are a god among men!! thank you so much ADyson!!!!